# Filter and map react with right number of components but wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to filter out and I show online the active / close or all projects (this is based with the status variable '1' - all , '2' - active and '3' - close) and in the array there is Active part that might be 0 (close) or 1 (active).
With the below techinique it appears the right number of components for example 3 or 4 but wrong components for example it is always show the first 3 component not the right 3 components that are active

```
var status = ((this.state.value2 === '1')?true: (this.state.value2 === '2')?0:1);
  

    var filter = ((filterRadio === 4)? this.state.projects.filter((product,index) => (product.Active !== status) ).map((product,index) => (
      <Grid
        item
        key={index}
        lg={4}
        md={6}
        xs={12}
      >
        <ProductCard
          className={stylesMain.productCard}
          product={product}
        />
      </Grid> .... continueee
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve with this change:

```
var filter = ((filterRadio === 4)? this.state.projects.map((product,index) => (
      (((status === true) ||(product.Active === status))?
      <Grid
        item
        key={index}
        lg={4}
        md={6}
        xs={12}
      >
        <ProductCard
          className={stylesMain.productCard}
          product={product}
        />
      </Grid>:null)
```